# How do I view a page created in locomotivecms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locomotivecms

I created a page in locomotivecms, under my app/views/pages folders and called it page2.liquid.haml and it contains the following code.

```
 {% extends 'index' %}

{% block 'main' %}This is the content for the page 2{% endblock %}
```

I can view the index page, but I am not sure how to view page2 in the browser everything I try leads to a 404.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above the liquid markup, you need to have a YAML file header with the page's title, slug, and published flag, like this:

```
---
title: Page 2
slug: page2
published: true
---
{% extends 'index' %}

{% block 'main' %}This is the content for the page 2{% endblock %}
```

You can create files with such headers generated automatically by using the `wagon generate page` command.

```
$ bundle exec wagon generate page test_page
```